# Synchronizing object in Cycles

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, baking

I have a model of a butterfly that uses a displacement map for most of the detail on the mesh at render time. To get an accurate render, I have it subdividing 4 times for the render before applying the displacement map.

While it gives me great detail, the downside is that I then have to wait a while for it to start rendering as it goes through a long "synchronizing object" stage on every frame. I'm assuming this is when it calculates the displacement on the object? I'm not entirely sure what this is doing.

Is there a way to bake this information or get around this step without spending so much time on it? This project has potentially quite a few frames to render at 1080p, so any way to lessen that is welcome.

Comment: Maybe the new Open SubDiv will increase the render performance and reduce the calculation time. http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Ref/Release_Notes/2.76/OpenSubdiv

Comment: [This BA thread](http://www.elysiun.com/forum/showthread.php?304042-Increasing-render-speed-by-skipping-sync-(Cycles)) is basically talking about the same thing, not that there is much of an answer there.